# Reload View only when application is opened Again

Tags: iphone

My application has tab bar with one of the tabs having a segmented control on navigation bar.
Based on segment clicked different view  is displayed using a url.
I am calling the url in  viewdidload method.I do not want to use viewwillAppear to call the url as it will be called each time the view is displayed.
I only want to call the url again whenever user closes the application and comes back.

Whats the best way to do this.Should I remove the view controller from and reload it again once the application is opened.

Comment: you really need to re-write your question. its hard to understand what the intent is.

Comment: I have re-write the question.Does it makes some sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use a more descriptive title for your question next time!

There are notifications for this that you can observe in your application:

`UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` come to mind.